# Why do MCUs typically have so little buffering on the USARTSs?

Tags: uart, buffer

I am currently working with Atmel AT91SAM7X256. It has a CAN i/f with multiple multibyte message boxes. However, the USARTs only have a single byte of buffering, which is a bit of a pain when I'm trying to do RS485 packet based stuff.

Comment: Because it costs money. And most of the MCUs I was working with had some sort of FIFO of at least 8 bytes long. But you really should consider using DMA.

Comment: [historical hypothesis]  Historically, the UART data rates tend to be fairly low.  So, an ISR for UART can receive a byte and stash it to a buffer in RAM.  This isn't DMA, though, because it isn't direct.  [DMA hypothesis]  On newer microcontrollers UART may be intended to work with DMA.  Here's an article [AT91SAM7 Serial Communications](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/DevTools/SAM7/at91sam7%20serial%20communications.pdf) which goes into using DMA with UART.

Comment: Back in the day, there were the 16550 parts (and similar) that included 16 byte FIFOs and interrupt capability on half-full (and other locations.) But an MCU has plenty of memory and the hardware cost of a separate FIFO for this purpose probably hasn't been worth it. I think RS-485 has been supported up to 100 Mb/s, though. For MCUs that are intended to support such high rates, like this one, there is a DMA module present and it even supports two sets of pointers and counts. So you have hardware support.

Comment: @jonk You could say the same for the CAN Bus

Comment: CAN is different. It has kind of flow control and collision detection built-in

Comment: DMA is essential.  Back in 1977 using an HP9825 to HP9825 doing my custom SCADA remote control, it was the only way  possible to establish error free without overflow with continuous data coming back and critical data analysis without delay for a remote rocket ground launch control system with 4x 50 wire unbilicals.

Answer (score 11):

Your AT91SAM7X256 has 13 DMA Controller channels and 64 KB of RAM. It is more efficient to make the RAM general purpose and use the DMAC to store transmitter and receiver data.

If RAM is instead put in little clumps for FIFOs etc, it can't be used for other purposes in non-UART applications. Having two things that do the same job - FIFOs and DMAC - is not a good use of transistor resources.

Your software typically would move the data between the FIFOs and the RAM anyway. Transmitting would be RAM->FIFO->TxUART but now it's RAM->TxUART. Similarly, receiving would be RxUART->FIFO->RAM but now it's RxUART->RAM.

Using the DMAC, the transmit and receive buffer sizes can be decided by your software, dividing up the RAM as you see fit.

Answer (score 3):

The primary usefulness of a FIFO stems from its ability to avoid having to have the CPU interact with individual character events in time-critical fashion.  If a chip's hardware can take care of *all* time-critical responses to individual character events, that may allow serial-port handling to be assigned a lower priority than would otherwise be necessary, thus allowing the chip to better meet the timing needs of other processes.

Unfortunately, a FIFO in and of itself isn't usually enough to meet timing requirements, and in some cases might actually be more of an obstacle rather than a help.  If, for example, a connection uses xon/xoff signalling (antiquated, perhaps, but sometimes still required in the absence of other handshaking wires) and a device receives an xoff, it should defer the transmisison anything past the current character in the transmit buffer.  For a chip which has a large transmit buffer to talk reliably to a device that has a small receive buffer and uses xon/xoff signalling, it must either have a means of pausing transmission without clearing the buffer [extra hardware] or else refrain from ever putting more bytes in the buffer than the receiver would be able to handle past the xoff [which would require having a way for the transmitter to know how many bytes were in the buffer--again, extra hardware].

Further, no matter how large a chip's receive buffer might be, it would need to be constantly grabbing all the data from the receive buffer any time it was transmitting in order to look for an xoff unless a received xoff can be detected without looking for everything [yet again, more hardware].

Some hardware UART devices that are designed to be polled sparsely (e.g. USB-to-serial converters) to have rather large FIFOs in them, but they also have hardware to allow them to react autonomously to a number of external events.  For  a large buffer in a built-in UART to be really useful, it would need to have hardware along with it that wouldn't be needed so much when using a smaller UART.

All that having been said, the argument that DMA eliminates the need for a large buffer doesn't totally hold water.  If external requirements would require that an application handle all serial-character events within three character times, a using a double-buffered UART with no DMA may ease software response time requirements compared with a single-buffered one and no DMA, while being much more convenient than using DMA.

Answer (score 2):

On an MCU, there's no reason to have dedicated hardware for large UART buffers, since it's so easy to do the same thing in the general-purpose RAM using interrupts and/or DMA.

That way, chip users who don't need that kind of buffering for their UARTs can use the memory for something else.

With the CAN interface, the timing constraints are more strict and the message length has a fixed limit. Plus, it might take multiple attempts to transmit a message, so it makes sense to to buffer entire messages rather than bytes.